# How to get last date on max count transaction_id by branch in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to get last date on max count txn_id base on branch_name.
This is the data

[image]

I want the result like this
[image: result]

```
 here is my script. but I get only one row.
```

```
select max(date),
   account,
   branch_name,
   province,
   district
from
(select date,
   account,
   branch_name,
   province,
   district,
   RANK() OVER (ODER BY txn_no desc) rnk
from
(select count(tr.txn_id) txn_no,
   tr.date,
   u.account,
   b.branch_name,
   b.province,
   b.district
from transaction tr
inner join users u
 on u.user_id = tr.user_id
inner join branch b
 on b.user_id = u.user_id
where 1=1
 and tr.date >= to_date('01/04/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') and tr.date < to_date('30/04/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
group by tr.date,
   u.account,
   b.branch_name,
   b.province,
   b.district
 ))
where rnk = 1
 group by tr.date,
   u.account,
   b.branch_name,
   b.province,
   b.district
```

Comment: What if some user have 2 different branches with equal max amount? what output do you need in this case?

Comment: Select only one DBMS (remove excess tag) - either OracleDB or MySQL, not both. Also specify precise server version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION user, branch) cnt
          FROM source_table ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY cnt DESC) rnk
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte2
WHERE rnk = 1
```

If more than one branch have the same amount of rows then all of them will be returned. If only one of them must be returned in this case then according additional criteria must be used and ORDER BY expression clause in `cte2` must be accordingly expanded. If any (random) must be returned in this case then `RANK()` in `cte2` must be replaced with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Is this Oracle?

Comment: @Strawberry Must work in both OracleDB and MySQL 8+ (OP uses window functions in his attempt).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with `SELECT TOP 1 ...` instead of `RANK()`, something like:

```sql
SELECT date,
  txn_id,
  account,
  branch_name,
  province,
  district
FROM transaction t
WHERE branch_name = (
  SELECT TOP 1 branch_name 
  FROM (
    SELECT branch_name, count(*) as cnt
    FROM transaction
    WHERE account = t.account
    GROUP BY branch_name
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
  ) s
  AND date = (
    SELECT TOP 1 date 
    FROM (
      SELECT date, count(*) as cnt
      FROM transaction
      WHERE account = t.account
        AND branch_name = (
          SELECT TOP 1 branch_name 
          FROM (
            SELECT branch_name, count(*) as cnt
            FROM transaction
            WHERE account = t.account
            GROUP BY branch_name
            ORDER BY 2 DESC
          ) s2
      GROUP BY branch_name
      ORDER BY 2 DESC
    ) s2 
  )
```

If there are multiple transactions on the last date, they all are going to be returned though.

Comment: overly complex solution

Comment: offer a simpler one, it would be more helpful

Comment: `TOP 1` - AFAIK neither MySQL nor Oracle support that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You want the most recent transaction from the account/branch with the most transactions.  If so, you can do this as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(cnt) over (partition by account) as max_cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by account, branch_name) as cnt,
                   row_number() over (partition by account, branch_name order by date desc) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where max_cnt = cnt and seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  If there are multiple branches that have the same count, then they are all returned.  Your question does not specify how to deal with such duplicates.